# Compare two dates in Java, one obtained from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

I need to compare two dates in Java, but the date obtained from database comes not with the same value as inserted.

```
@Test
public void testCompareHoraHardcore() {
    String sql = "update solicitacao_viagem set "
            + "hora_retorno=?, id_veiculo=?, id_responsavel_solicitacao=?, "
            + "id_responsavel_autorizante=? where id_solicitacao_viagem=? ";
    Timestamp timestamp1 = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setTimestamp(1, timestamp1);
        stmt.setInt(2, 90);
        stmt.setInt(3, 337);
        stmt.setInt(4, 337);
        stmt.setInt(5, 91);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Timestamp timestamp2 = null;
    try {
        sql = "select * from solicitacao_viagem where id_solicitacao_viagem=?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, 91);
        stmt.executeQuery();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        timestamp2 = rs.getTimestamp("hora_retorno");
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assertEquals(timestamp1.getTime(), timestamp2.getTime());
}
```

This test return:

```
Testcase: testCompareHoraHardcore(com.model.dao.SolicitacaoViagemDAOTest):  FAILED
expected:<1360553289573> but was:<1360553289000>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1360553289573> but was:<1360553289000>
at com.model.dao.SolicitacaoViagemDAOTest.testCompareHoraHardcore(SolicitacaoViagemDAOTest.java:349)
```

Why MySQL is cutting the three last numbers?

I'm using MySQL 5.5.22 and Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21).

The column "hora_retorno" is TIMESTAMP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd have to check the documentation, but it could be that MySQL is storing the timestamp in seconds not in milliseconds...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, MySQL doesn't store fractional seconds in Timestamp columns (or other datetime types either).  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: Thanks =D. But how I store e retrive DateTime values from database to compare in Java? Using Java Date or change the column to DATETIME, or two?

Comment: You could round the millisecond values to the nearest thousand.

Answer (score 3):

MySql stores `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` to **seconds** precision. Here is a quote from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

```
A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds
part in up to microseconds(6 digits) precision. 

Although this fractional part is recognized, 
it is discarded from values stored into DATETIME or TIMESTAMP columns
```